# Beanshell PostProcessor Error: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List;

Tags: jmeter

I am getting error message

> Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List; import
>   java.util.concurrent.Time . . . '' : Typed variable declaration :
>   Error in method invocation: Static method create( java.lang.String )
>   not found in class'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster'

when I execute jmeter script with Beanshell Post Processor. Any thoughts on why I am seeing this error?

Here is the sample code:
    import java.util.Arrays;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.Document;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;

Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("dev-int-couchbase1.aeg.cloud");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("source-image ",100, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
Document<JsonObject> loadedFromDoc = bucket.get("0292ofcfh4516");
if(loadedFromDoc == null)
    return "Document Not found";

bucket.remove(“0292ofcfh4516");
log.info("In bean shell processor");
System.out.println("In bean shell processor");
cluster.disconnect();
return "Document Removed";
```

Comment: what is the JMeter version? where did you keep the couchbase-client-java  jars? in `/lib` folder? what all libraries required?

Comment: I am using 2.11 ,yes. I have kept them in lib folder

Comment: please let me know what all libraries required and the links to download them

Comment: http://eglisa.dtvops.net/hotDeploy/

Comment: You need the two couchbase jars and the rxjava one

Comment: Your question contained answer to my question. I was looking for the package information that contains the TimeUnit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `create(String... varargs)` method, suggest using `create(List<String> nodes)` method.

replace the following code

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("dev-int-couchbase1.aeg.cloud");
```

With:

```
nodes = new ArrayList();
nodes.add("dev-int-couchbase1.aeg.cloud");
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(nodes);
```

Note: I am not sure how to fix the issue related to `varargs`, so suggesting another one. I tried suggested method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202176/2575259), but did not work for `varargs`.

Reference:

1. http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/index.html?com/couchbase/client/java/CouchbaseCluster.html

---

I suggest use [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead of `BeanShell postprocessor`. Just copy paste the code from `BeanShell` to `JSR223` and select the language as `Java` under `script language` drop-down available in the `JSR223 post processor`.

This gives more flexibility in debugging (prints complete stack trace of the error/exception in the logs).

---

Coming to the error, it says that `Static method create( java.lang.String ) not found in class'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster`. I checked in the official docs [here](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.0/index.html?com/couchbase/client/java/CouchbaseCluster.html), which says there is a `create` method which takes `String Varargs`. I ma not sure whether that is causing the issue. so, try it out in JSR223 PostProcessor and debug the issue.

References:

1. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance

Comment: @kmm, updated my answer. try with `create(List<String> nodes)` method which is also available in the CouchbaseCluster class. this approach is working for me.

Comment: Thank you naveen. I have used JSR223 Pre Processor and updated the code as per your comments.

Comment: found below error message:jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script  javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List; import java.util.concurrent.Time . . . '' Encountered "=" at line 16, column 36.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List; import java.util.concurrent.Time . . . '' at line number 16

Comment: nodes = new ArrayList();
nodes.add("dev-int-couchbase1.aeg.cloud");
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(nodes);
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("source-image",100, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
Document<JsonObject> loadedFromDoc = bucket.get("0292f666e15eut");
if(loadedFromDoc == null)
    return "Document Not found";
    bucket.remove(“0292f666e15eut");
cluster.disconnect();
return "Document Removed";

Comment: Try the code in answer with beanshell post processor itself and let me know. I checked in beanshell and I was working for me.

Comment: Thanks much Naveen... Few small minor issues in my code.. I have resolved them and working fine... Thank you again